PendingIntent with sdk 34
I have this function that shows a hint with phone number:
private void requestHint() {
        HintRequest hintRequest = new HintRequest.Builder()
                .setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)
                .build();
        PendingIntent intent = Credentials.getClient(getApplicationContext()).getHintPickerIntent(hintRequest);
        mGooglePhoneResult.launch(new IntentSenderRequest.Builder(intent.getIntentSender()).build());
    }

When I passed to sdk 34, I get an error:

Targeting U+ (version 34 and above) disallows creating or retrieving a PendingIntent with FLAG_MUTABLE, an implicit Intent within and without FLAG_NO_CREATE and FLAG_ALLOW_UNSAFE_IMPLICIT_INTENT for security reasons. To retrieve an already existing PendingIntent, use FLAG_NO_CREATE, however, to create a new PendingIntent with an implicit Intent use FLAG_IMMUTABLE.

Any suggestion ?
